# How to activate "Installed" programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is an `UIView` and I want to activate it (with its constraints etc.), when I want, how to do that? I don't want `removefromsuperview` etc. Just want to learn this `Installed` function exact equivalent in terms of code.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two options 1) `hide` 2) `removeFromSuperview`.

If You `install` or `uninstall` view  from `storyboard`, It is equivalent to `add/remove` view.

refer this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html) it says,

> A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However, the view and any related constraints are not added to the view hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil. This is different from being hidden. A hidden view is in the view hierarchy along as are any related constraints.

you can check this by two line of code,

```
 NSArray *arr = [self.view subviews];
 NSLog(@"arr is %@",arr);
```

swift:

```
let array: Array = self.view.subviews
print("Array is \(array)")
```

try it with installed and uninstalled. 
hope this will help :)

Comment: Great, only a detail, the second option method is removeFromSuperview exactly, in swift 4.